# ¿Cómo puedo exportar métodos de vue.js a un archivo de javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Son varias funciones que quiero exportar a javascript pero me sale el error de  "uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function" in JavaScript
Esta es una de las funciones que quiero exportar:

```
export default:{
  methods:{
     getLogin_user: function(){
        login_user(this.user, this.status_anexo,this.status_login).then((data)=>{
           console.log("Incio de sesion con exito")
           this.getLimpiar_cola(this.user);
        })
         this.limpiar_cola();
     },
   }
}
```

Al exportar a javascript utilizo:
import { getLogin_user } from '../progresivo/index.vue'

Comment: Tu función está dentro de un objeto llamado `methods`. Tal vez deberías usar `import { methods } from '../progresivo/index.vue'` y luego llamar a `methods.getLogin_user`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, gracias por contestar.  Lo he probado pero me sale error de: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getLogin_user'),

Comment: Claro, disculpa no vi que tienes `export default`. Debes hacerlo así: `import obj from '../progresivo/index.vue'`. Luego lo puedes usar así: `obj.methods.getLogin_user`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, muchas gracias. me ayudaste mucho lleve batallando con ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás exportando un objeto al usar `export default`. Este objeto contiene una clave llamada `methods` que es a su vez un objeto que contiene otra clave llamada `getLogin_user` que es la función que deseas usar.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una forma de acceder al método que necesitas es la siguiente:

```js
import obj from '../progresivo/index.vue';
```

Y luego usar el método de la siguiente forma:

```js
obj.methods.getLogin_user();
```

Otra forma podría ser la siguiente:

```js
import obj from '../progresivo/index.vue';
// ...
const { methods } = obj;
methods.getLogin_user();
```

Puedes encontrar más información de `export` en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.